# Incorrect output when averaging in python

Tags: python

There is no error appearing in this python code but the output is incorrect. This is a code about calculating the average marks of a student.

```
english_1 = 22
urdu_1 = 23
maths_1 = 15
science_1 = 18
social_1 = 21

english_2 = 10
urdu_2 = 22
maths_2 = 13
science_2 = 25
social_2 = 11
```

```
def average_marks(english, urdu, maths, science, social):
    average = english + urdu + maths + science + social / 5
    print("average marks of student")
    print(average)
```

```
result1 = average_marks(english_1, urdu_1, maths_1, science_1, social_1)
result2 = average_marks(english_2, urdu_2, maths_2, science_2, social_2)
```

this is the output

average marks of student
82.2
average marks of student
72.2

If you can pls help i am a beginner.
Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

You are missing parentheses when calculating the average. You want to make the sum first and then make the division:

```
average = (english + urdu + maths + science + social) / 5
```

Hopefully I was of any help

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me but one thing
Try setting result1 to a double or a float instead of a int
therefore when python writes the result it will not encounter any restrictions
and add parentheses around lie this

```
(english + math + science) / # of items
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

*'Order of Operation'* shows that division takes procedence of addition. Your problem lies within the following:

```py
average = english + urdu + maths + science + social / 5
```

Using brackets around the addition section of the code, division will be taken out **after** the brackets. Like so:

```
average = (english + urdu + maths + science + social) / 5
```

**Further Notes**

To tidy your code up a bit, I would suggest reducing positional parameters in the function and nest your results in a dictionary. Like so:

```py
student_results = {'Student1':{'English':22,'Urdu':23,'Maths':15,'Science':18,'Social':21},
                   'Student2':{'English':10,'Urdu':22,'Maths':13,'Science':25,'Social':11}}

def average_marks(results):
    average = sum(results.values()) / len(results)
    return average

for student, results in student_results.items():
    print("The average results for Student {} is {}".format(student, average_marks(results)))
```